# d3.geoPath() returns Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M,ZM,ZM,ZM,Z"

Tags: geojson, d3.js

Edit: recreated the logic on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/exLtcgrq/1/

I am trying to parse a simple GeoJSON file to D3 using the D3 V4 API.

My GeoJSON is simple:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [10.0, 10.0], [60.0, 40.0], [50.0, 75.0],[20.0, 60.0]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "1",
        "Type": "campingspot"
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [20.0, 65.0], [50.0, 80.0], [50.0, 110.0],[20.0, 115.0]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "1",
        "Type": "campingspot"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I load thus using the d3.json() method and try using the d3-geo api to convert it to a path with this code:

```
var jsonData2 = d3.json("campingGeojson.json", function(error, json){
        svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(json.features)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("d", d3.geoPath())
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1)
          .attr("fill", "green")
      });
```

The console output on chrome tells me the following

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M,ZM,ZM,ZM,Z".
```

Any suggestions what is going wrong with using the geoPath method is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder would a jsfiddle of the code be helpful to answer your error.

Comment: Here you go :) https://jsfiddle.net/exLtcgrq/

Comment: Ok so I'm getting geoPath() is not a function. `TypeError: d3.geoPath is not a function`

Comment: Sorry JSFiddle doesn't have v4 yet. Added it on https://jsfiddle.net/exLtcgrq/1/

Comment: In the JSFiddle why are you commenting this line out? 
`//var jsonData2 = d3.json("geoJson", function(error, json){`

Comment: As this references to a json file which I wasn't able to add. Therefore the data is in the javascript and referenced by a variable, this also works ( according to the working example generating a polygon ). Locally the commented out example also works using that syntax, that shouldn't be part of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coordinates for geoJson polygons are an array of coordinate arrays (with the coordinates themselves being arrays). The first array indicates the shell, following arrays indicate holes. 
So I think your geoJson should look more like:

```
"coordinates": [
 [ [10.0, 10.0], [60.0, 40.0], [50.0, 75.0],[20.0, 60.0] ]
    ]
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot. GeoJson was was also quite new for me but I assumed the fault would be with D3  as it was such a basic geoJson !